# Is it necessary for MSBuild to transpile .ts files in Angular2's dependencies (in node_modules) for Angular2 to work?

Tags: node.js, asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript, msbuild

## Background

I've got an ASP.NET MVC project integrated with Angular2.  Per the [Angular.io](http://www.angular.io/) quick-start guide - I created a folder in my solution file with the default Angular2 structure...

```
├── app
|   └── ...
├── node_modules
|   └── ...
├── typings
|   └── ...
| systemjs.config.js
| tsconfig.json
| typings.json
| package.json
```

... and a default `package.json` file:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
  "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
  "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
  "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
  "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
  "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
  "systemjs": "0.19.27",
  "zone.js": "^0.6.23",
  "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
  "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
  "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
  "typescript": "^2.0.2",
  "typings":"^1.3.2"
}
```

Then I used the `npm install` command to install Angular2's dependencies into the `node_modules` folder.

## Problem

The root of my problem is that MSBuild is attempting to compile every `.ts` file in the entire project.<sup>1</sup>  These include `.ts` files that it finds in the `node_modules` folder. This throws a lot of errors and prevents the solution from being built/published.<sup>2</sup>

## Question

I can solve the problem by deleting all `tsconfig.json` files except for the one at my project's root level - if so, MSBuild will stop trying to compile AngularJS' dependencies in `node_modules`.

But is this advisable?  Will the Angular2 dependencies work correctly if their `tsconfig.json` files are removed, and their Typescript files are not compiled?  Will SystemJS compile the Typescript files anyway?

<sup>1</sup> I am using the `Microsoft.Typescript.MSBuild` NuGet package to transpile `.ts` files (tsc.exe v2.0.3) and NodeJS v6.x.

<sup>2</sup> I think this is because *before* the Angular2 dependencies are installed, I have a single `tsconfig.json` file at my project's root - but *afterwards*, `node_modules` contains like ten different `tsconfig.json` files - for instance, `\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\rx\ts\tsconfig.json`.

Comment: I use Asp.net MVC and angular2 together.  However, I never develop an ng2 project using Visual Studio (I got too annoyed by these kinds of problems).  Rather, I create my project using angular-cli; develop the project  within Visual Studio Code (which is awesome).  THEN when it is time to build for production, I run "ng build -prod" and use gulp to copy everything in the "prod" folder to my asp.net MVC project.  Not the answer you were looking for, but thought it may be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

> Will the Angular2 dependencies work correctly if their tsconfig.json files are removed, and their Typescript files are not compiled?

Third party libraries are already distributed as JS files. This is true about any third party library. Libraries that support TypeScript out of the box, will include [TypeScript Definition Files](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/05/19/using-typescripts-type-definition-files-to-get-tooling-support-for-plain-javascript) (these files end in `.d.ts`). When we compile our applications, they get compiled against against the definition file, *not* the source (`.ts`) file. The definition file provides the typing which is enough for TypeScript to compile against. We should never have to touch the actual source code

You may have also noticed that some third-party JS libraries don't support TypeScript out of the box (.i.e. don't distribute typing in the library). In which case, we need install an external third-party typings. For example, say we are using Moment JS. If you install `npm install momemt`, you will notice the module has not typings file. So if we want to use Moment in TypeScript, we would `npm install @types/moment`, and that would provide us with the typings for Moment.

Also if you wanted to create your own TypeScript library, what you would do is add `compilerOptions.declaration: true` to your `tsconfig.json` file. When the project is compiled, it will create definition files for you, so that you don't need to manually write them.

This is how third-party libraries are/should be consumed in TypeScript. If we didn't use definition files, and always imported the source, then the source would always get compiled, whether or not you exclude it from tsconfig, as the code we are writing depends on it. So instead we depend on definition files. When you import into your project code, what you're importing is actually the definition file, not the source file.

Comment: This answers part of my question - I'm hearing that the .ts files do not need to be compiled.  What about the `tsconfig.json` files?  MSBuild is compiling every `.ts` file where it finds a finds a `tsconfig.json` - even in `\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\rx\ts\tsconfig.json`

Comment: It shouldn't if you exclude node_modules. If it does, it might be an IDE (or whatever MSBuild is) specific problem

Comment: I can exclude `node_modules` on the root `tsconfig` - makes sense.  However, going into the individual Angular2 project dependencies' `tsconfig` files (which are consumed by MSBuild) and overwriting all of them with `exclude`s seems dangerous.

Comment: I don't know, I don't use MSBuild. But using node's global typescript compiler, I never have the problem with other tsconfig files also being used.

Comment: +1 and this totally makes sense in the context of the NodeJS ecosystem.  My question though is really about MSBuild behavior where it tries to resemble NodeJS, so I've edited my question's title accordingly.

Comment: @peeskillet but how do you include `moment` in then output bundle? the `.ts` files compiles because of `.d.ts` but then tsc doesnt know from `d.ts` where is the `moment.js`, how to provide link between `.d.ts`  and `.js`??

Comment: @entre you don't. There is no such connection. The typing (module) should be structured the same as the real module. When the `import * as moment from 'moment'` is used in TypeScript, at runtime, the module loader should be able to load the actual JS file from JS module based on the compiled `var moment = require('moment')`.

Comment: @entre same when using Angular modules. We aren't compiling against Angular source. We are using their d.ts. The JS is already compiles into a module. When we `import { Http } from '@angular/http'`, it gets compiled to `var Http = require('@angular/http')`. The `@angular/http` should be able to be loaded by the module loader from the Angular JS file, based on the location

Comment: As far as the moment library, there is not typings file, so you need to install the third party typings. `npm install --save-dev @types/moment`

Answer (score 0):

You should not compile TypeScript files under node_modules. To ensure that you don't, add the following to your tsconfig file:

```
"exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
```

It's considered a bad practice to publish a library as TypeScript since the consumer would have to recreate the entire build environment to use it - types and all. You would potentially also have to target a specific version of the TypeScript compiler.

Comment: So why not? I already know how to exclude them from compilation. Is the reason for this documented somewhere?

Comment: The code provided by third-part libraries is already compiled, you don't have to do it yourself, and you shouldn't

Comment: I added some more info